# Remote packet capturing using fifo and dumpcap

Tags: centos, ssh, firewall, wireshark, pipe

I'm currently working on two linux servers where one server is running in `2.6.18-274.el5`(Server A) and the second one in CentOS 7 (Server B).

My requirement is to capture the packets of the network interface of Server A from the Sever B. For that I've used the method mentioned in this [link](http://linuxexplore.com/2010/05/30/remote-packet-capture-using-wireshark-tcpdump/). I've used the same method mentioned in the resources except for the last step where instead of using wireshark, I used the fifo to create a packet dump using dumpcap since I want to monitor the interface in long run. Dumpcap will capture the fifo and save it into a single file which will be replaced after a certain amount of time is elapsed.

But the issue I'm having is that after executing these commands the dumpcap will capture packets for a some period of time and then halts.

I checked the log files of the sshd located in `/var/log/secure` and there was a record saying that `Apr 16 14:32:14 sshd[23070]: Read error from remote host <host>: Connection reset by peer`

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a log entry on the other server that says why ssh closed? If not, try running it with debug output, -v, I think

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.. I eventually found the issue it was a ip address conflict where another user was also using the same ip.. So that the session is terminated when ever such conflict occurs...